# Yii2 как сделать пригласительную ссылку (invite)

Tags: yii2

Все привет, у меня проект на YII2, объясните как мне сделать пригласительную ссылку.

Смысл такой, есть компания и она хочет пригласить сотрудника, допустим сотрудник получает на почте ту самую ссылку на регистрацию и когда он зарегистрировался то в таблице компании этот сотрудник есть в таблицы компании.
Я не могу понять как мне передать параметры когда я отправляю на почту ссылку.

Если у кого есть пример кинь.

Заранее спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Всё очень просто. У вас должен быть объект/модель/таблица "Инвайт|Приглашение", в которой можно хранить случайно генерируемую строку и другие данные (id компании, время окончания действия приглашения ...).

Компания отправляет приглашение на email. Вы, прежде чем отправить ссылку на этот email, генерируете случайную строку и записываете её в БД вместе с другими необходимыми данными, а в ссылку-приглашение подставляете эту же строку в виде GET параметра.

Сотрудник приходит по ссылке - читаем GET параметр, если находим такой инвайт в БД - завершаем регистрацию с данными о компании, которые есть в инвайте, затем инвайт можно удалить. Если не находим или время его действия истекло - перекидываем на страницу обычной регистрации к примеру.